# Is there any similar boilerplate like MEAN stack for SailsJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, sails.js, mean-stack

I have to develop a new blog for myself. I have recently got acquainted with AngularJS, mongoDB, node, sails, etc. I have got some primitive knowledge about all these to start the development.

So, I was looking for something similar to http://mean.io/, MEAN stack. But instead of using ExpressJS, I am gonna use SailsJS. Is there anything similar to MEAN but works with SailsJS as well? Or is there any other approach to the same, considering I am also gonna use AnuglarJS for front-end and mongoDB for my database?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

AFAIK, there's no branded Sails-based alternative to http://mean.io/ yet, though some people were talking about [MEANS stack](http://phillydotnet.org/talks/the-new-means-stack-with-sails-js-mongodbexpressangularjsnode-jssails-js/) already.

That being said, you have several choices for creating an Angular+Sails app. One of them is using Yeoman generator, like [this one](https://github.com/chiefy/generator-sails-angular).

Another way could be [this boilerplate](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails-angular-seed) which is somewhat official, as it's published by [Balderdash](http://balderdash.co/), the company behind Sails. Though when I tried to test it, dependency installation was failing, so I fixed it on [this fork](https://github.com/bredikhin/sails-angular-seed). This boilerplate is based on the brand new Sails v0.10. Also, you are going to have to do is to connect it to your MongoDB (the default is `sails-disk`), see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21598339/how-to-connect-with-mongodb-using-sailsjs-v0-10) for how-to.