# How to connect a project with different versions of MongoDB in different environments (localhost and Bluemix)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, sails.js, ibm-cloud

I want to set connect to "local mongodb" when I run my sails projects on my localhost and set connect to "MongoDB experimental" on Bluemix

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to connect with mongodb using sailsjs v0.10?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21598339/how-to-connect-with-mongodb-using-sailsjs-v0-10)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general you can have a config.js,

```
var dbconfig = {
        dev: "mongodb://localhost/mean-todo",
        prod: process.env.MONGOLAB_URI
}
```

connect using,

```
mongoRemote: {
    adapter: 'sails-mongo',
    url: dbconfig.prod || dbconfig.dev
  },
```

Hope this works!!